# Would the EM oscillation at a point become zero as soon as light has passed through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

It is said that light is a disturbance or oscillation in an electromagnetic field. If light passes through a certain point in space, would the oscillation cease to exist at the given point instantaneously once the light has passed through it, or would the oscillation or disturbance gradually decrease to zero? In the picture below, a laser pulse of an infinitesimal length $dx$ is travelling toward the right of screen, and passes through a point "X". Would the intensity of light or oscillation in EM field at point "X" go back to zero as soon as the rear end, "A", of pulse has passed through "X" point?

[image]

Let me try to elaborate. The amplitude of a point through through which the water wave passes will gradually decrease. The amplitude does not become zero instantaneously.

Comment: It is the same as for a short pulse of water or a string wave. If some oscillations remained for a while, it would not be a pulse so short anymore. By definition the wave is the disturbance.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Thanks. Are you saying that oscillation would persist for some time at the point "X"? In case of water waves, amplitude/oscillation doesn't go to zero instantaneously.